# (RFC-791) Application Layer PDU size, guaranteed to pass without fragmentation

Tags: networking, udp, mtu, fragmentation

I am writing a client-server python application, a part of which is using UDP Multicast to communicate. And my current concern is about fragmentation.

[RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791) (page 24) says:

> Every internet module must be able to forward a datagram of 68 octets
> without further fragmentation.  This is because an internet header may
> be up to 60 octets, and the minimum fragment is 8 octets.

By reading the above i understand that we can have an Application Layer PDU, 8 bytes of size, that can pass without fragmentation.
On Packet Tracer(an application where you can configure Routers in a Virtual environment), the minimum allowed MTU is 64 (see image below). This means that the Application Layer PDU guaranteed size can be 4 bytes?

[image]

I may not have understood this correctly, that's why i would like your help.
The question is: What should be the size of the Application Layer PDU, so that the IP packet that contains it can pass without being fragmented? 4 or 8 bytes?

Comment: Also please consider improving your question.  I am not entirely sure what your question is.

Comment: Can i do that ? Thanks, i will try to find out how to link my accounts and improve the question

Comment: @Athspk, go to [your accounts tab](http://serverfault.com/users/63416/athspk?tab=accounts) and see what it says.

Comment: @Chris I just cheched and it looks like they are [connected](http://serverfault.com/users/63416/athspk?tab=accounts). I may have done it in the past but i dont really remember.

Comment: I edited the question with the hope to be clearer.

Comment: Are you honestly planning to send 4 or 8 bytes of data using 64- or 68-bytes packets? I don't know your application requirements, but this looks *absurdly* inefficient...

Comment: Ah, clear the account association, and then re-associate them.  You'll get the bonus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RFC791 Specifies IP only.  Since you will be using UDP, you must read RFC791 in conjunction with [RFC768](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768) which specifies UDP.  The UDP Datagram header is 8 octets, including a two-octet length field with a minimum value of 8 (the length of the header).

At the minimum Layer 3 (IP) PDU of 68 octets, if you use UDP as your Layer 4 Protocol, the largest higher-layer data packet you can transmit without fragmentation (when the maximum IP Header length of 60 octets is used) is zero octets - the 8 octet minimum having been used by the UDP Datagram header!

If you wish to have an application layer packet of 8 octets using UDP over IP and you envisage the IP Header regularly reaching the maximum length of 60 octets, you will need a link with an MTU of 76 octets or greater to ensure your packets do not require fragmentation.

However, you should note that RFC791 also states (Page 13):

```
The maximal internet header is 60 octets, and a typical internet Header
is 20 octets
```

If you assume a typical Internet header size, over an (incorrectly configured) link with an MTU of 64 octets, you would still be able to transmit an application packet of 36 octets before fragmentation:

```
  MTU - IP_HDR - UDP_HDR
=  64 -     20 -       8
=  36 octets
```

However, in most real-world scenarios, you should not encounter networks with such small MTU's (unless you're talking to a PLC in the Embedded / SCADA world, or another similarly restricted environment).

Comment: And in-light of your amended question, the above explanation stands, with the brief answer of "neither"!